# Fix the flair display within post revision view

Tags: feature-request, design, revisions-list, flair

The post revisions view doesn't present a proper abbreviated reputation flair. In fact, it shows the full reputation as-is, without a thousand-separating comma. Can this be fixed?

Consider [the following example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/225370/revisions):

[image]

The problem is not really an issue, until you [view John Skeet's flair in the post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6841479/revisions), where content starts to stick into the margin:

[image]